# BBC Micro:Bit : possible to detect WebUSB?

Tags: uart, webusb, bbc-microbit

I'm got a BBC Micro:Bit 2.21 and I'm writing code using micropython on https://python.microbit.org/ .

I have tried to find a way to know if the Micro:Bit is connected to a browser using WebUSB or to something else using a normal USB connection but I haven't found any way.

The reason for this is that the WebUSB serial prompt in Chrome looks better when outputting strings with `\r\n` but my program normally uses `\n` when communicating with a Raspberry Pi.

Is there a way to detect if the Micro:Bit is connected using WebUSB or not?

Comment: "WebUSB serial prompt in Chrome": Chrome doesn't include a WebUSB serial prompt. Newline behavior would be decided by the terminal app, not Chrome. Perhaps you can modify the terminal app to work the way you want? I don't think the micro:bit receives any info about the app on the other end.